# Cakephp raw query with paramaters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

Is it possible to do something like this in CakePHP?

```
            $messages = $this->Message->query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE
                 (from_id = :id AND to_id = :user_id) OR
                 (to_id = :id AND from_id = :user_id)
                 ORDER BY created DESC", 
                 array(
                    'id' => $id,
                    'user_id' => $user_id
                )
            );
```

Comment: Yes - read up on [Prepared statements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#prepared-statements)

Comment: Why would you WANT do to this though?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$messages = $this->Message->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'OR' => array(
            array('from_id' => $id, 'to_id' => $user_id),
            array('to_id' => $id, 'from_id' => $user_id),
        ),
    ),
    'order' => array(
        'created' => 'DESC',
    )
));
```